# Benefit of the doubt that a person is a Jew?

Tags: gentiles, embarrassment

If a person in conversation makes a brief reference to the fact that they converted through Rabbi ___ (and there is a person with that name who is a reform "rabbi" in that region), is it permitted to assume that the person is therefore a reform convert and not a halachic Jew?  Or is there standard under Halacha that must be followed regarding giving them the benefit of the doubt?

Comment: I revised the question to get to heart of the point of my question.  I'm hopeful it will be unmarked as a duplicate.

Comment: It seems like your question is whether one  may assume the person is not Jewish or must instead assume he is Jewish. To what end? Under normal circumstances there's never a requirement to assume someone is or is not Jewish. Only when you want to trust his say-so about kosher food, or count him toward a _minyan_, or accept his testimony in court, or other circumstances, is there such a requirement. Are you asking about one of those? all of them? I think you should edit to clarify.